# how to mock navigator.clipboard.writeText in vue test utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to test copy to clipboard in nuxt, but test case can't cover `navigator.clipboard.writeText`, how to test navigator stuff, i also have tried **shallowMount**
and **mount** but both not working,

```
<template>
  <span v-b-tooltip.hover class="url" title="Copy" data-test="copyUrl" @click="handleCopy(listing.url)">
    <i class="fa fa-copy" aria-hidden="true"/>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ............
  methods: {
    ..............
    handleCopy(url) {
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(url);
    }
    ...............
  }
  ........
};
</script>


// test case
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';

// componenet
import Table from '@/components/Listings/Layouts/Table.vue';

const wrapper = shallowMount(Table, {
  attachToDocument: true,
});

describe('Table.vue', () => {
  it('check handleCopy', () => {
    wrapper.find('[data-test="copyUrl"]').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

Comment: Sometime answer can be just 2 feet away from you... :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
window.__defineGetter__('navigator', function() {
  return {
    clipboard: {
      writeText: jest.fn(x => x)
    }
  }
})
```

Try this

Answer (score 2):

This method allows you to test `readText` and `writeText`, as well as allowing your tests to check what was written to the clipboard. This will also work in TypeScript, whereas `window.__defineGetter__` will throw an error.

```
let clipboardContents = "";

Object.assign(navigator, {
    clipboard: {
        writeText: text => { clipboardContents = text; },
        readText: () => clipboardContents,
    },
});
```

If you are using jest, use the correct methods:

```
let clipboardContents = "";

Object.assign(navigator, {
    clipboard: {
        writeText: jest.fn(text => { clipboardContents = text; }),
        readText: jest.fn(() => clipboardContents),
    },
});
```