# Why is the second Jest mock function never being called?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I am mocking `navigator` functions for simple clipboard functionality. Here is the relevant code:

```
// FUNCTION

/**
 * Adds a click event to the button which will save a string to the navigator clipboard. Checks for
 * clipboard permissions before copying.
 */

function loader(): void {
  async function copyUrl(): Promise<void> {
    const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "clipboard-write" });
    if (permission.state == "granted" || permission.state == "prompt" ) {
      await navigator.clipboard.writeText("the url");
    } else {
      console.error('Permission not supported');
    }
  }

  const button = document.querySelector('button') as HTMLElement;
  button.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    await copyUrl();
  });
}
```

```
// TEST

it('works', () => {
  // mock navigator functions
  Object.assign(navigator, {
    permissions: { 
      query: jest.fn(async () => ({ state: "granted" }))
    },
    clipboard: { 
      writeText: jest.fn(async () => {})
    }
  });

  // initialize DOM
  document.body.innerHTML = '<button></button>';
  loader();    // adds the event listener

  // click the button!
  const button = document.querySelector('button') as HTMLElement;
  button.click();

  expect(navigator.permissions.query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the url');
});
```

The test fails on `expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the url')` with:

`Expected: "the url" Number of calls: 0`

Defeats the purpose of permissions, yes, but for the sake of debugging:
Try adding a clipboard call before permissions call like so?

```
// FUNCTION

// ...
async function copyUrl(): Promise<void> {
  
  // add this
  await navigator.clipboard.writeText('the url');

  // keep the rest still
  const permission = await navigator.permissions.query({ name: "clipboard-write" });
  // ...

}
```

This fails on the first assertion now, `expect(navigator.permissions.query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` with

`Expected number of calls: 1   Received number of calls: 0`

With the addition above, I also changed the assertions to be:

```
expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledWith('the url');
expect(navigator.clipboard.writeText).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
expect(navigator.permissions.query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

... which failed on the second assertion because it expected 2 calls but only received 1.

I have been testing in a VSCode devcontainer and tried out the extension `firsttris.vscode-jest-runner` to debug the test. With breakpoints in the `loader` function, I'm able to see that every single line executes perfectly with my mockup but still fails at the end of debug.

I even changed the mock `navigator.permissions.query` function to return `{ state: 'denied' }` instead. Both running and debugging, it did not satisfy the permission check and gave an error to the console as expected but the test still failed at `expect(navigator.permissions.query).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` (with the added `writeText` call before it).

It seems to me that after the first call of a mock function, the others just don't work.

Am I missing something? Send help pls lol

**EDITS**

Using `jest.spyOn` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356286/2902063) has the same issues.

Using an async test with an `expect.assertions(n)` assertion still produces the exact same issue.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356286/2902063) maybe you'll find some inspiration there. I expect the issue is with async and your test not being async.

Comment: @alextrastero I've already looked at that answer extensively. Same issue. Tried in an async test as well before posting with `expect.assertions` and it's the same issue. The loader is synchronous anyways and promises are all awaited.