# Jest test - test contents of clipboard after execCommand('copy') executes

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

My team runs a website created with React. For various reasons, I need to use the deprecated `document.execCommand('copy')` method of copying to the clipboard. When writing jest unit tests, I am mocking `execCommand` and making sure it was called with `expect(document.execCommand).toHaveBeenCalledWith('copy');`

I want to test the actual contents of the clipboard after copying. Is there a way to test for this using jest?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Quoting from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62356286/6595024):

> Jest tests are running in the JSdom environment and not all of the properties are defined, but you should be able to define the function before spying.

I would recommend mocking the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), as that is a more modern way of reading and writting to the user's clipboard.

(Unless, your test is very simple. In which case I'd say it's not worth the trouble)

Edit: There's some discussion on how to do this [in an open issue on jsdom's repository](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1568)